# How to fix 404 path error for Angular2/TypeScript ASP.NET 4.6.1 on VS2015

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to build a new app using TypeScript, Angular2 and ASP.NET 4.6.1 on VS2015. I am experiencing two problems.

**First:** I am getting 404 errors on the include files in my index.html file. When I open F12 developer tools in Chrome I see this:

```
GET http://localhost:58613/app/app/lib/es6-shim.min.js
```

As you can see, it's trying to go to **app/app/** but my files are in **app/lib/**. Why is this happening? Chrome reports a 404 error on all of this. However, it doesn't report a 404 error on my .css files (the index.html file in included in this post further down).

Second: When I run the app and it opens in IE (version 10, my default browser) I see this error:

**0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined**

When it hits this code:

```
System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          //format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
```

My directory structure is such:

```
/app/
  index.html
  --Main/
      boot.ts
      boot.js
  --lib/
      various .js files moved via gulp
  --Components
```

My index.html file is such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Toastr-->
    <link href="lib/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/toastr.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/system-polyfills.src.js"></script>

    <script src="app/lib/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/rx.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/http.dev.js"></script>


    <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          //format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/Main/boot')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));

    </script>

    <my-app>Hello World</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

tsconfig.jscon

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening? What do I have to do to get this setup correctly?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i see the cause.

Your index.html is under /app/index.html

so all the script import is relative to the directory that this **index.html** file is in.

for example:

```
<script src="app/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
```

It means "/app/app/lib/es6-shim.min.js".  It is not there, so you get a 404

Simple change it to:

```
<script src="lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
```

and for others as well.  It will solve the problem.

Comment: Adding <base href="/"> fixed it. I had tried changing the src on the includes, as you suggested, but I was still left with the System undefined error. Adding the base href to the top of my index.html fixed the whole thing.